# Start session after destroying it in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

In my program I am making sure that the previous user is logged out by destroying its session before logging in the next one, but after destroying the session with `$this->session->sess_destroy()` I only get errors when trying to log the next user in (session related operations)

How can I restart the session?

Thanks

Comment: Destroy the session, redirect to another page to re-start the session giving the correct $_SESSION['']; params.

Comment: So the only way is to make a redirect? Can't it be done in the same process?

Comment: Theres many ways, but just experiment, learn from mistakes

Answer (score 0):

When destroying session, which you are doing right, you have to redirect or re-load your url to make session re-start.